# Plotting a Cox PH model using ggforest in RStudio when a factor is stratified?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survminer

I am trying to find a way to make a forest plot of hazard ratios from a Cox-PH model when one of the model variables needs to be stratified. For a non-stratified model, the `ggforest()` function is excellent. Running some example code

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

model <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + rx + adhere,
               data = colon )
ggforest(model)

colon <- within(colon, {
  sex <- factor(sex, labels = c("female", "male"))
  differ <- factor(differ, labels = c("well", "moderate", "poor"))
  extent <- factor(extent, labels = c("submuc.", "muscle", "serosa", "contig."))
})
bigmodel <-
  coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + rx + adhere + differ + extent + node4,
        data = colon )
ggforest(bigmodel)
```

produces this graph

[image: non-stratified figure]

However if I have to correct for non-proportionality with stratification

```
stratamodel <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + strata(rx) + adhere + differ + extent + node4,
                     data = colon )
ggforest(stratamodel)
```

The following error message appears:

> "Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , var) : undefined columns selected

In addition: Warning message:

> In .get_data(model, data = data) :   The `data` argument is not
> provided. Data will be extracted from model fit."

Any suggestions for how to get the information that ggforest needs from the strata model so that it can produce a plot? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887495/ggforest-function-returns-error-message-when-used-with-coxph

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. The challenge is that answer is not really an option for the real data set I'm working with, where the stratified variable is a treatment with levels that needs to be corrected for in the model but not interpreted, necessitating the strata function. It seems ggforest is pretty much a wrapper for ggplot so I was wondering if there was a way to make it work. Unfortunately I'm more of an ecologist picking up r tricks as I go so am not sure if what I'm asking is feasible

Comment: As you noted, `ggforest` is a wrapper, so coding with the underlying ggplot should certainly work. The issue here is that the pool of SO users who are familiar with both stratified models *and* ggplot2 may not be very large. If you can include a rough sketch of what the stratified model's plot should look like, your chances of getting help would probably increase.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Z.Lin, If graphing using the example code, the stratified model would look like the image in the original question, but with slightly different values due to the stratification and not including the rx treatment, which was stratified.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I gather that the desired forest plot is one that simply skips the stratified RX variable in the model's formula. If so, we can simply insert an if clause inside, to ignore formula parts that don't correspond exactly to column names in the data (e.g. "strata(rx)" is not a column name).

## Approach 1

If you are comfortable with R sufficiently to modify functions, run `trace(ggforest, edit = TRUE)` and replace the `allTerms <- lapply(...)` (around lines 10-25) in the pop-up window with the following version:

```
allTerms <- lapply(seq_along(terms), function(i) {
  var <- names(terms)[i]
  if(var %in% colnames(data)) {
    if (terms[i] %in% c("factor", "character")) {
      adf <- as.data.frame(table(data[, var]))
      cbind(var = var, adf, pos = 1:nrow(adf))
    }
    else if (terms[i] == "numeric") {
      data.frame(var = var, Var1 = "", Freq = nrow(data), 
                 pos = 1)
    }
    else {
      vars = grep(paste0("^", var, "*."), coef$term, 
                  value = TRUE)
      data.frame(var = vars, Var1 = "", Freq = nrow(data), 
                 pos = seq_along(vars))
    }
  } else {
    message(var, "is not found in data columns, and will be skipped.")
  }
  
})
```

```
ggforest(stratamodel) # this should work after the modification
```

[image: plot]

The modification will not persist to subsequent R sessions. If you want to reverse the modification within the current session, simply run `untrace(ggforest)`.

## Approach 2

If you prefer to have a permanently modified version of the function for future use / don't want to muck around with a library's function, save the function below:

```
ggforest2 <- function (model, data = NULL, main = "Hazard ratio", 
                       cpositions = c(0.02, 0.22, 0.4), fontsize = 0.7, 
                       refLabel = "reference", noDigits = 2) {
  conf.high <- conf.low <- estimate <- NULL
  stopifnot(class(model) == "coxph")
  data <- survminer:::.get_data(model, data = data)
  terms <- attr(model$terms, "dataClasses")[-1]
  coef <- as.data.frame(broom::tidy(model))
  gmodel <- broom::glance(model)
  allTerms <- lapply(seq_along(terms), function(i) {
    var <- names(terms)[i]
    if(var %in% colnames(data)) {
      if (terms[i] %in% c("factor", "character")) {
        adf <- as.data.frame(table(data[, var]))
        cbind(var = var, adf, pos = 1:nrow(adf))
      }
      else if (terms[i] == "numeric") {
        data.frame(var = var, Var1 = "", Freq = nrow(data), 
                   pos = 1)
      }
      else {
        vars = grep(paste0("^", var, "*."), coef$term, 
                    value = TRUE)
        data.frame(var = vars, Var1 = "", Freq = nrow(data), 
                   pos = seq_along(vars))
      }
    } else {
      message(var, "is not found in data columns, and will be skipped.")
    }    
  })
  allTermsDF <- do.call(rbind, allTerms)
  colnames(allTermsDF) <- c("var", "level", "N", 
                            "pos")
  inds <- apply(allTermsDF[, 1:2], 1, paste0, collapse = "")
  rownames(coef) <- gsub(coef$term, pattern = "`", replacement = "")
  toShow <- cbind(allTermsDF, coef[inds, ])[, c("var", "level", "N", "p.value", 
                                                "estimate", "conf.low", 
                                                "conf.high", "pos")]
  toShowExp <- toShow[, 5:7]
  toShowExp[is.na(toShowExp)] <- 0
  toShowExp <- format(exp(toShowExp), digits = noDigits)
  toShowExpClean <- data.frame(toShow, pvalue = signif(toShow[, 4], noDigits + 1), 
                               toShowExp)
  toShowExpClean$stars <- paste0(round(toShowExpClean$p.value, noDigits + 1), " ", 
                                 ifelse(toShowExpClean$p.value < 0.05, "*", ""), 
                                 ifelse(toShowExpClean$p.value < 0.01, "*", ""), 
                                 ifelse(toShowExpClean$p.value < 0.001, "*", ""))
  toShowExpClean$ci <- paste0("(", toShowExpClean[, "conf.low.1"], 
                              " - ", toShowExpClean[, "conf.high.1"], ")")
  toShowExpClean$estimate.1[is.na(toShowExpClean$estimate)] = refLabel
  toShowExpClean$stars[which(toShowExpClean$p.value < 0.001)] = "<0.001 ***"
  toShowExpClean$stars[is.na(toShowExpClean$estimate)] = ""
  toShowExpClean$ci[is.na(toShowExpClean$estimate)] = ""
  toShowExpClean$estimate[is.na(toShowExpClean$estimate)] = 0
  toShowExpClean$var = as.character(toShowExpClean$var)
  toShowExpClean$var[duplicated(toShowExpClean$var)] = ""
  toShowExpClean$N <- paste0("(N=", toShowExpClean$N, ")")
  toShowExpClean <- toShowExpClean[nrow(toShowExpClean):1, ]
  rangeb <- range(toShowExpClean$conf.low, toShowExpClean$conf.high, 
                  na.rm = TRUE)
  breaks <- axisTicks(rangeb/2, log = TRUE, nint = 7)
  rangeplot <- rangeb
  rangeplot[1] <- rangeplot[1] - diff(rangeb)
  rangeplot[2] <- rangeplot[2] + 0.15 * diff(rangeb)
  width <- diff(rangeplot)
  y_variable <- rangeplot[1] + cpositions[1] * width
  y_nlevel <- rangeplot[1] + cpositions[2] * width
  y_cistring <- rangeplot[1] + cpositions[3] * width
  y_stars <- rangeb[2]
  x_annotate <- seq_len(nrow(toShowExpClean))
  annot_size_mm <- fontsize * 
    as.numeric(grid::convertX(unit(theme_get()$text$size, "pt"), "mm"))
  p <- ggplot(toShowExpClean, 
              aes(seq_along(var), exp(estimate))) + 
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = seq_along(var) - 0.5, 
                  xmax = seq_along(var) + 0.5, 
                  ymin = exp(rangeplot[1]), 
                  ymax = exp(rangeplot[2]), 
                  fill = ordered(seq_along(var)%%2 + 1))) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FFFFFF33",  "#00000033"), guide = "none") + 
    geom_point(pch = 15, size = 4) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = exp(conf.low), ymax = exp(conf.high)), 
                  width = 0.15) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = 1, linetype = 3) + 
    coord_flip(ylim = exp(rangeplot)) + 
    ggtitle(main) + 
    scale_y_log10(name = "", labels = sprintf("%g", breaks), 
                  expand = c(0.02, 0.02), breaks = breaks) + 
    theme_light() +
    theme(panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), 
          legend.position = "none", 
          panel.border = element_blank(), 
          axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
          axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
          axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
    xlab("") + 
    annotate(geom = "text", x = x_annotate, y = exp(y_variable), 
             label = toShowExpClean$var, fontface = "bold", 
             hjust = 0, size = annot_size_mm) + 
    annotate(geom = "text", x = x_annotate, y = exp(y_nlevel), hjust = 0, 
             label = toShowExpClean$level, 
             vjust = -0.1, size = annot_size_mm) + 
    annotate(geom = "text", x = x_annotate, y = exp(y_nlevel), 
             label = toShowExpClean$N, fontface = "italic", hjust = 0, 
             vjust = ifelse(toShowExpClean$level == "", 0.5, 1.1),
             size = annot_size_mm) + 
    annotate(geom = "text", x = x_annotate, y = exp(y_cistring), 
             label = toShowExpClean$estimate.1, size = annot_size_mm, 
             vjust = ifelse(toShowExpClean$estimate.1 == "reference", 0.5, -0.1)) + 
    annotate(geom = "text", x = x_annotate, y = exp(y_cistring), 
             label = toShowExpClean$ci, size = annot_size_mm, 
             vjust = 1.1, fontface = "italic") + 
    annotate(geom = "text", x = x_annotate, y = exp(y_stars), 
             label = toShowExpClean$stars, size = annot_size_mm, 
             hjust = -0.2, fontface = "italic") +
    annotate(geom = "text", x = 0.5, y = exp(y_variable), 
             label = paste0("# Events: ", gmodel$nevent, 
                            "; Global p-value (Log-Rank): ", 
                            format.pval(gmodel$p.value.log, eps = ".001"), 
                            " \nAIC: ", round(gmodel$AIC, 2), 
                            "; Concordance Index: ", round(gmodel$concordance, 2)), 
             size = annot_size_mm, hjust = 0, vjust = 1.2, fontface = "italic")
  gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
  gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off"
  ggpubr::as_ggplot(gt)
}
```

It's a snapshot of the `ggforest` function *as it currently stands*, with the same modification as above. If the package's creator makes modifications to the package in the future, this can break or become outdated. But for now, `ggforest2(stratamodel)` will yield the same result as Approach 1.

Comment: that is exactly what I needed and worked perfectly, thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59887495/4745348) noted, `ggforest` looks at `attr(model$terms, "dataClasses")[-1]` to get the model terms.

So let's just give it what it wants?

```
library(dplyr)

ggforest(stratamodel, data = colon %>% mutate(`strata(rx)` = rx))
```

[image: forest plot output]

By cross-checking with the `summary(stratamodel)` output, this seems to be correct.

We are, unfortunately, left with the unnecessary rows for the strata. Perhaps there is a way to deal with this.

EDIT: There is!

We try a different strategy, we change the attributes of the model, so that the `ggforest` function doesn't search for these terms.

```
attr(stratamodel$terms, "dataClasses") <- attr(stratamodel$terms, "dataClasses")[-3]
ggforest(stratamodel, data = colon)
```

[image: forest plot output]

We have what we needed.

Comment: This answer doesn't work.

Comment: More information please? Run all the code from the question.